# Creating an end-of-chapter Exercise environment

Tags: environments

I would like to define two environments: `chapterexercises` and `exercise`, which will
appear at the end of each book chapter.  Output format sample:

> ```
>   Homework Exercises for Chapter 3  (centered, top of new page)
>
>   The Direct Stiffness Method (centered chapter title
> ```
>
> EXERCISE 3.1 [A:15]. Using the method presented in ....
>
> EXERCISE 3.2 [C:20]. Program the method outlined in ...
>
> etc. etc.

The environments would be invoked as

```
\begin{chapterexercises}

\begin{exercise}[A,15]

Using the method presented in ....

\end{exercise} 

\begin{exercise}[C,20]

 Program the method outlined in ...

\end{exercise} 

\end{chapterexercises}
```

I have written those in PlainTeX long ago (1984) supporting Course Notes (one
Chapter per lecture) and I am now converting to a LaTeX book for a publisher.
Any similar existing implementation that can be quickly tweaked?

Comment: You've not given much to work with, but have you looked into the `enumitem` package?

Answer (score 1):

This pulls together a few things:

- `enumitem` allows you to define an enumerate with a custom label and heading.
- `xstring` allows you to substitute the `,` to become `:`.
- A little bit of trickery to account for the blank line after `\begin{exercise}` (that may come back to haunt you).
- Saving the current chapter name into a macro.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\let\savepar=\par
\newcommand{\resetpar}{\let\par=\savepar}

\let\savechapter=\chapter
\newcommand{\currentchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\renewcommand{\currentchaptername}{#1}\savechapter{#1}}

\usepackage{xparse} % not necessary for TeXLive 2021+
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{chapterexercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[chapterexercises]{
    label={EXERCISE \arabic{chapter}.\arabic*},
    before={
        \clearpage\centering
        Homework Exercises for Chapter \arabic{chapter}\\
        \currentchaptername
    }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{o}{%
 \item{}\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{[\StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{:}].}
 \let\par=\resetpar
 % swallow one \par to allow one blank line after the environment begins.
 % (This does mean that if the blank line isn't there,
 % then the second paragraph will merge into the first.)
}{}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{The Direct Stiffness Method}

Chapter content.

\begin{chapterexercises}
\begin{exercise}[A,15]

Using the method presented in ....

\end{exercise} 

\begin{exercise}[C,20]

Program the method outlined in ...

\end{exercise} 

\begin{exercise}[D,20]

Program the method outlined in ...

A second paragraph to make sure par has been reset.

\end{exercise} 

\end{chapterexercises}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]